# Visual Studio 2019 not creating OBJ or BIN folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So basically I'm trying to create a simple console application. However, whenever I create one instead of seeing the usual run button I am instead greeted to a button that says attach so I read through forum after forum and I found out that I need an OBJ and a Bin folder. So I looked through my solution and found that I have no bin or obj folder created. So I tried to make a new solution however in this new solution again there is no bin or obj folder. I honestly don't know what to do anymore. Here are some images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you run the BUILD step ? are they not showing up in visual studio but are present in your file system ? have you tried to repair your VS ?

Comment: Stop thinking about the bin and obj folders. They will be created when compilation takes place. I am more intrigued by how you manage to not have a Run button.

Comment: Did you open the project or just the source file?

Comment: David Browne I opened both however none have it.

Comment: Off to a good start re making sure all the software on your machine is properly installed and correctly license-activated!

Comment: Yes, I think @DavidBrowne-Microsoft understood what you're doing wrong. When I try to open just a file, e.g. Program.cs, then an Attach button is shown. I guess you are either not creating a solution in the first place, or you are creating a solution and then later trying to open just a file.

Comment: Bent Tranberg I also have that question.

Comment: Can you press windows-G and record a movie of you making a new project?

Comment: Mauricio Gracia Gutierrez I have not because I cannot the run/build button is not there it only says attach.

Comment: You need to add the project to the solution before you can build or debug.

Comment: @ScottyD0nt, that's just confusing. A solution and a project is not normally created separately, but at the same time. See my answer.

Comment: [What are Visual Studio Solutions and Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) .. and ... [Create a new project in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-new-project?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are actually creating a solution in Visual Studio. The straightforward way to do that is to use **File / New / Project...** in the menu. Then you will likely have a dialog box, and there you need to find **Console Application - C#**. Then type your project and solution name - it's ok if they're the same name. Then save. That's all.

Do not use the menu to open Program.cs or other files in your solution, once your solution is created. Use the Solution Explorer, and click on the file you want to see. If you don't see the Solution Explorer, use **View / Solution Explorer** in the menu.

Later, when you want to reopen your solution, use **File / Open / Project/Solution...** in the menu, and open your solution file, whose name ends with `.sln` Or even easier, look in **File / Recent Projects and Solutions**.

You will likely want to add more source files to your projects very soon, so I'll tell you how to do that too. In the Solution Explorer, right click on the project (not the solution), and in the popup menu, point at **Add** and then **New Item...** to get a dialog, then choose **Class - C#**. Type the name of the file while keeping the extension `.cs`, and then **Add** it.

Comment: In my solution there is no project and I cant run it! Any fixes for that? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LMkh.png)

Comment: There's File/Add/New Project...  but I fear you'd just add to some mess if you try. It could be that there's already a project on disk, in which case you'd use File/Add/Existing Project... to try to fix. When you successfully create a new solution with a new project, there will be a solution folder with a .sln-file and a project folder inside.

Comment: It's easier to just start from scratch, and study what you get then in order to learn the ropes.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me but my problem still stands... Visual studio 2019 even after creating a new project (fresh) still says Attach instead of Run and I still cant run my solution.

Comment: In the Solution Explorer, right click on the console application. In the popup menu, select Set as Startup Project. Does this change "Attach" to something else?

Comment: And before I get too far ahead, do you have a solution with a project in Solution Explorer now? If you do, at least we're on the right track. If not, ...

Answer (score 0):

The process should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably likely that there is an issue with dotnet on your path variable. Go to your system variables and add `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` to path. It should fix the issue if you had the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have been building a console app that can run on .NET Core and you just don't have the NuGet packages installed.  Then you need to either install the appropriate packages or create a console application (.Net Framework)